# Insert fixed number of elements in list after each existing elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one list of ip addresses:

```
ip_list = ['10.7.0.151', '10.7.0.152', '10.7.0.153', '10.7.0.154', '10.7.0.155', '10.7.0.156', '10.7.0.157', '10.7.0.158']
```

I need to insert 6 null elements and 'Total' in the same list after all the ip address elements like this:

```
ip_list = ['10.7.0.151', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Total', 
           '10.7.0.152', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Total',
            . . .
           '10.7.0.158', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Total']
```

Can someone suggests if there is any way to insert elements in above manner? or I need to take this hard-coded list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *list comprehension* should do. Create a new iterable by adding the new items to the ip and then unwrap with a nested for in the comprehension:

```
lst = [i for x in ip_list for i in (x,)+('',)*6+('Total',)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would produce a second list, by iterating the first and appending the necessary elements on each pass:

```
original_list = ['1.2.3.4', '5.6.7.8']
extended_list = []

for item in original_list:
    extended_list.append(item)
    for i in xrange(6): extended_list.append('')
    extended_list.append('Total')
```

There's a thousand clever one-liners that can achieve the same, but this is simple and flexible enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

`map` and `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce    # python3+


reduce(lambda m,n: m+n, map(lambda x: [x]+['']*6+['Total'], ip_list))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that `reduce` is a builtin in Python 2.7, so there's no need to import

Comment: I was trying to provide a version agnostic answer, but I will clarify the answer.